# How to make class active user clicks on perticular page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to make the class active when user clicks on perticular link for navigation menu 
I am new in php code igniter so how can make it dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have 4 pages and there page id's are 1,2,3,4 than you can do it like that

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home" class="<?php echo ($page_id==1?'active':'')?>" >Home</a><span>|</span></li>

<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about" class="<?php echo ($page_id==2?'active':'')?>" >About Us</a><span>|</span></li>

<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>services" class="<?php echo ($page_id==3?'active':'')?>" >Services</a><span>|</span></li>

<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>en/contact" class="<?php echo ($page_id==4?'active':'')?>">Contact Us</a></li>
```

I hope it 'll help you!!